# Laravel without database connection

Tags: laravel

is there a way to use Laravel without database connection? I am planning to create a frontend website using blade and VueJS that will consume third-party API and I don't need a database.

Currently, I am getting this error and I am not sure how to bypass it.

```
Database name seems incorrect
You're using the default database name laravel. This database does not exist.

Edit the .env file and use the correct database name in the DB_DATABASE key
```

Comment: @Padarom I can't see solution there...

Comment: Can you post the actual value of the `DB_DATABASE` from your .env?

Comment: Just use sqlite driver.

Comment: Laravel is a backend framework? Why would you want to use Laravel without it? Just use blade and vue seperately.

Comment: are you trying to use Eloquent models or migrations? If you don't then there is no need for database at all.

Comment: No. It'a default laravel 6.0 application

Comment: What is the stacktrace in what context does this fail? we need some more information.

Answer (score 13):

if you using internal artisan service for development server, you need to restart service:

`Ctrl + c`

then run

`php artisan serve`

Comment: Unfortunately this causes php artisan serve to run 10+ minutes before I give up.

Answer (score 3):

This check appeared in Laravel 5.6.29, through the Ignition service's `DefaultDbNameSolutionProvider`.

The solution message is a bit misleading, since it presumes you want to use a database. It's trying to convey that (a) you're configured to use a default database<sup>†</sup>, and (b) that default database does not exist, so (c) you should change the database name to the actual value for your environment.

Since you don't have a database, set `DB_DATABASE=unused` and you should not get this error any more. Of course, if you call `DB::connection()`, that will blow up. But that's expected.

---

<sup>†</sup> The two database names Laravel recognizes as default are `"laravel"` and `"homestead"`.

Answer (score 3):

Every change you make to the `.env` file you need to restart your server.

So you need to stop service by `Ctrl + C`, killing process if you run in detached state or stop your Docker etc. Then run again with `php artisan serve` or rerun your Docker container.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Homestead as your development environment, you should change `DB_DATABASE` from `laravel` to `homestead`, `DB_USERNAME` to `homestead` and `DB_PASSWORD` to `secret`.

> A homestead database is configured for both MySQL and PostgreSQL out
>   of the box. To connect to your MySQL or PostgreSQL database from your
>   host machine's database client, you should connect to 127.0.0.1 and
>   port 33060 (MySQL) or 54320 (PostgreSQL). The username and password
>   for both databases is homestead / secret.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#connecting-to-databases

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but if someone needs this when you update your .env file you must restart your server to effect those new setting so close current running server `C+ctrl` then again run `PHP artisan serv`