# Is there any way to bypass using database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

I'm using `Laravel` version `7.x` where having trouble to access a property value inside my view template.
It's showing the following exception:

`Trying to get property 'image_name' of non-object (View: F:\Laravel\doorsoft_job_assignment\resources\views\images\image-list.blade.php)`

And showing me solution:

**Database name seems incorrect
You're using the default database name laravel. This database does not exist.
Edit the .env file and use the correct database name in the DB_DATABASE key.**

I have attached the exception & solution to have a more clear view as image.

[image: Here is the image]

Anyway, I'm passing data to view from a `.json` file. Where array of objects contains on that `.json` file. I'm returning data from that file instead of via Model. I don't want to use Database for **CRUD**

**Note:** I have already searched similar problem and found something to set `DB_DATABASE = unused` to fix the problem from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908247) but that solution not fixed my problem.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please include error messages as text rather than images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. In my view file, by writing `$img['image_name']` instead of writing `$img->image_name` has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a need to use the database here. You can access your data like this from your JSON file.

```
$data = Storage::disk('local')->exists('data.json') ? 
        json_decode(Storage::disk('local')->get('data.json')) : [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, laravel is using database name as laravel. Maybe your Database name is different. Possibly, cache is still there. Properly check your database schema name. Check your .env file and replace DB name, password, host and run the following command

```
php artisan config:cache
```