# Laravel without database configuration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel but, i do not want any database connectivity. i do not need any database to use for my site. if i delete `config/database.php` still **error**. 
Also if i delete DB config from `.env` still issue. 
Is there any way to use laravel without any **database configuration**.

```
[1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'
```

and

```
database[] not configured
```

Thanks

Comment: Check if `DB_DATABASE=unused` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908247/1213708 fixes it.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Answer (score 1):

dont delete any file just blank credentials blank and laravel app work without any connection

blank credentials in .env file

Comment: You also need to point the session to either file or cookie, and not database

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQlite database driver, create an empty database in storage directory.
No need to write anything there too.

The only requirement will be that your php will need sqlite extension enabled, but that will be on by default, probably.

Comment: i just want without any config is this possible?

Comment: It's literally a few lines of config.

Comment: yeah but why i need this?